# Windows 10 and Ubuntu Dual Boot with separate ESPs

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

Recent Windows 10 feature update ruined my dual boot. I want to install Ubuntu again. However, I would like to use a different EFI partition than Windows for Ubuntu. I aim to avoid the described situation where Windows update destroys dual boot. If I select "Something Else' while installing and create a new EFI partition, Ubuntu still installs all boot files in Windows EFI partition. The newly created partition remains empty. How can I dual boot Ubuntu with Ubuntu and Windows boot files in separate ESPs?

Comment: Not required & not really the issue. Both Windows & Ubuntu/grub on major updates reset system to be first in boot order. Windows also turns fast start up back on which prevents grub from booting Windows, so you have to turn it off again, by directly booting into Windows. What brand/model system? You really can only have one working ESP per device. If you have two drives then you can have another ESP on second drive.

Comment: I know it's not required and there are ways to fix grub. However, some other distros, such as Pop OS and Manjaro, offer the functionality to choose the ESP during the installation process. You don't have to worry about Windows update messing up your dual boot or grub. Also if you want to uninstall you just delete the Linux partitions and you are done. If I uninstall Ubuntu, where the ESP is same is Windows, I have to use Windows fix start-up tool. Also, I didn't understand this "You really can only have one working ESP per device". I have used dual boot systems with 2 ESPs.

Comment: I think everyone else other than Ubuntu let you choose ESP. And we have complained for years. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 Do you have two ESP, or one FAT32 that was an ESP and second as ESP. UEFI uses GUID to find files. Not sure then if once flag is moved to second ESP, if it still boots from first. And grub does not care, so will find .efi boot files in any FAT32 partition. Change mount of ESP in fstab and reinstall grub to another ESP. You can also use efibootmgr to create entry specifying partition. see `man efibootmgr` -d for drive & -p for partition.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will check if that works out. The bug was reported in 2014. Don't know why it hasn't been addressed. May they treat it as required functionality and want the system to behave in that particular way?